# How To Fetch Data into My Datatable in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

I want  to Fetch Data into My Datatable I'm getting THis Error:
index.js:1 ***Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.***
This is the Code if Somone can help me :

```js
    import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, ScrollView,Text, View, Modal } from 'react-native';
    import { DataTable } from 'react-native-paper';
    import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
    import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
    
    import COLORS from '../src/conts/colors';
    import Button from '../src/views/components/Button';
    
    
    const List = ({navigation}) => {
    
    
    
         const [data,setData] = useState([])
         const [loading,setLoading]= useState(true)
    
    
         const fetchData = ()=>{
            fetch("https://flow.simpas.ai/hortus/paysagiste/category?businessid=0899607494")
            .then(res=>res.json())
            .then(results=>{
    
                setData(results)
                setLoading(false)
    
    
            })
         }
    
         useEffect(()=>{
              fetchData()
         },[])
    
    
      const renderList = ((item)=>{
    
        return(
    
          <DataTable.Row style={styles.tableRow} key={item.businessid}>
                <DataTable.Cell textStyle={{color: '#777777',fontFamily: 'Roboto'}} onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Edit",{item})} >{item.title}</DataTable.Cell>
                <DataTable.Cell textStyle={{color: '#FEB296', fontFamily: 'Roboto'}}>{item.title}</DataTable.Cell>
                <DataTable.Cell textStyle={{color: '#777777', fontFamily: 'Roboto'}}>{item.price}</DataTable.Cell>
            </DataTable.Row>
        )
      })
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1}}>
      <ScrollView
        contentContainerStyle={{paddingTop: 50, paddingHorizontal: 20}}>
        <Text style={{color: COLORS.black, fontSize: 40, fontWeight: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Roboto',textAlign: 'center'}}>
          List of Companies
        </Text>
        <Text style={{color: COLORS.grey, fontSize: 18, marginVertical: 10, fontFamily: 'Roboto', textAlign: 'center'}}>
          Check Our Companies Details
        </Text>
      <DataTable style={styles.container}   >
      <DataTable.Header style={styles.tableHeader}  >
        <DataTable.Title textStyle={{color: '#fff',fontSize: 16, fontFamily: 'Roboto'}}>BusinessId</DataTable.Title>
        <DataTable.Title textStyle={{color: '#fff',fontSize: 16, fontFamily: 'Roboto'}}>Title</DataTable.Title>
        <DataTable.Title textStyle={{color: '#fff',fontSize: 16, fontFamily: 'Roboto'}}>Price</DataTable.Title>
      </DataTable.Header>
      </DataTable>
        {renderList}
      </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    
    
    );
    };
    
    export default List;
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        padding: 0,
    },
    tableHeader: {
      backgroundColor: '#50E3C2',
    },
    tableRow: {
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
    },
    
    });
```

**This is The capture of the Error:**

[image: iamge]

Comment: Likely needs to be `{renderList()}` instead of just `{renderList}` without the `()`.

Comment: @zero298 I believe is correct (though there may be more issues. React components are functions that return Elements. In this case you have returned the **function** rather than the result of that function (a call).

Comment: I tried {renderList()} instead of just {renderList} But it's not Working

Comment: `renderList` also looks like a mapping function.  What data are you expecting to be given to that function.  Looking more closely, it should probably be something like `{SOME_DATA_ARRAY.map(renderList)}` such that ever element in `SOME_DATA_ARRAY` is turned into a `<DataTable.Row/>`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please use `{renderList()}` instead of `{renderList}`.
2. Use `{renderList()}` between `</DataTable.Header>` and `</DataTable>`...and not after `</DataTable>`.